# osqa markdown and flatpages in admin

Tags: django, markdown, django-flatpages, osqa

I have a markdown problem with OSQA and `flatpages` in admin. To be specific markdown is not recognized, i.e. instead of `**` I just get `<strong>` as the output.

Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: I'm confused, do you mean `**` instead of `<strong>` actually?

Comment: The text surrounded by ** should be marked as strong, i.e. be bold. But what I get is the same text surrounded by <strong> and </strong>.